# Install supervisor in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I'm trying to install supervisor for my laravel project in a php container. I followed all the steps to add it, but it's not installed. when I go into to container and execute whereis supervisor returns empty. but when execute same line inside container "apt-get install -y supervisor", it is installed.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
RUN apt-get update
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis && pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/

# RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini

# Install Laravel dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libxml2-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv mbstring xml pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

COPY JobQueues-worker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/JobQueues-worker.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n", "-c",  "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/JobQueues-worker.conf"]
```

Comment: From within the container, what does `dpkg -l | grep supervisor` say?

Comment: @whites11 nothing, returns empty.

Comment: That means that the package is not installed. Are you 100% sure that the above is the Dockerfile you used to build the image? Could you share the `docker build` log?